# How to get xml Node name and Inner Text and Fill Grid view

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have One XML file, showing Below,

Now I dont know number of its nodes under "appsetting" element.
I am trying to fill grid view using this XML file, somehow like
Gridview have column of node name like tag 1, tag 2, tag 3... etc
And have one row which have corresponding tags values like val 1, val 2, val 3..

I try somemy self, but i am not getting how to fetch inner value without giving Node Name.
I try this,

```
       XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(XmlPath);
        XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("appSettings");
        foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Tag1");
            dt.Columns.Add("Tag2");
            dt.Columns.Add("Tag3");
            DataRow dr;
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Tag1"] = xn["Tag1"].InnerText;
            dr["Tag2"] = xn["Tag2"].InnerText;
            dr["Tag3"] = xn["Tag3"].InnerText;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dgv.DataSource = dt;
        }

        dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dgv.ReadOnly = true;
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got This Answer With Help of @ Arin Ghazarian ,
I just Modify little bit in his code,,

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(XmlPath);


        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (XmlNode xn in doc.ChildNodes[0])
        {
            string tagName = xn.Name;
            if (!dt.Columns.Contains(tagName))
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(tagName);
            }

        }
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        foreach (XmlNode xn in doc.ChildNodes[0])
        {

            dr[xn.Name] = xn.InnerText;


        }
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
doc.Root.Elements().Where(xe => xe.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("tag", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

**EDIT:**

If you have different tag names like but the format is like `<Tag>Value</Tag>` you can iterate through `Elements` and get value of each node like this:

```
        List<List<Tuple<string, string>>> tuples = new List<List<Tuple<string, string>>>();

        //if you have more than one row, some how you xml should be formatted hierarchically,
        //so you need to create an outer loop here and iterate through parent nodes (rows):
        List<Tuple<string, string>> tuple = new List<Tuple<string,string>>();
        foreach(var node in xdoc.Root.Elements())
        {
            string nodeName = node.Name.LocalName;
            if (!dt.Columns.Contains(nodeName))
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(nodeName);
            }
            tuple.Add(Tuple.Create(nodeName, node.Value));
        }
        tuples.Add(tuple);

        foreach (var row in tuples)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            foreach (var r in row)
            {
                dr[r.Item1] = r.Item2;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

Comment: here just for example i write node names start from "TAG" word, but I have Different Name like Tag1, Identity, DataBase_Path etc...

Comment: Oh OK, I thought you just have 'Tag' elements. I'll update my answer.

Comment: the Word "Root", "LocalName" not supported.
foreach (XmlNode xn in doc.Root.Elemets())
            {
              string tagName = xn.Name.LocalName;

Lines Showing Error..
String Does not Contain Defination Of Local Name

Comment: Use `System.Xml.Linq`

Comment: Also note that my answer is just an example, I'm trying to edit it to give you what you exactly wanted.

Comment: I've updated my answer and tried my best to get you what you wanted, but note that your xml should be organized hierarchically for achieving what you wanted. Any how this example will work for your xml and since your xml has only one row so it will be added to your data table. Any how, the whole idea here is to use `node.Root.Elements()`

Comment: I got Answer by little modification in your code which was u post earlier,
now i also check your upper code, and if its works i will mark it as answer,
thank you very much for your help